# How update full object with linq to entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want update object with linq to entities, like this :

```
  public ActionResult SubmitPool(SwimmingPool Pool)
        {

            SwimmingPool IsPool = (from sp in db.SwimmingPool
                                   where sp.Id == Pool.Id
                                   select sp).First();


            if (IsPool != null) {

                IsPool = Pool;
                  db.SaveChanges();
                }
}
```

But It doesn't...

If I does :

```
  public ActionResult SubmitPool(SwimmingPool Pool)
        {

            SwimmingPool IsPool = (from sp in db.SwimmingPool
                                   where sp.Id == Pool.Id
                                   select sp).First();


            if (IsPool != null) {

               ----> IsPool.Name = Pool.Name;
                  db.SaveChanges();
                }
}
```

It does! But I want Update Full object. How do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
IsPool = Pool;
```

does nothing to the data within; it simply changes the reference.
After that line, both `IsPool` and `Pool` point to the same object in the heap; not useful in your case.
You have to specifically assign each member from one class to the other.

Answer (score 1):

use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for map between your view models and linq entities

Comment: using AutoMapper would slow him badly ! i think he should automapper in more critical situations not simple one like this ,